# What happens if 2 genes have the same connection but a different innovation number?

Tags: neural-networks, genetic-algorithms, evolutionary-algorithms, neat, neuroevolution

I have read the [Evolving Neural Networks through Augmenting Topologies (NEAT)](http://nn.cs.utexas.edu/downloads/papers/stanley.ec02.pdf) paper, but some doubts are still bugging me, so I have two questions.

1. When do mutations occur? Between which nodes?
2. When mating, what happens if 2 genes have the same connection but a different innovation number? As far as I know, mutations occur randomly and thus it is possible that 2 genomes have the same mutation.

Answer (score 2):

> When do mutations occur and between which nodes?

There are two types of mutations in the *NEAT* model, each of them appears randomly during one epoch on different individuals; the number of structures affected by mutations may vary depending upon the nature of the problem.

- A new gene/node is added to the structure and properly linked.
- A new connection between two nodes is added.

> When mating, what happens if 2 genes have the same connection but a different innovation number?

During a single epoch/generation every mutation is tracked and if the same mutation appears it can't have the same global *innovation* number. *Same mutation, same innovation number.* In that way, during the mating phase, there is no decisional problem which leads to prefer one structure to the other.